# Is it possible for a hacker to make a website clone with HTTPS?

Tags: security, ssl, https, dns, web

I've seen this question around here on the forums only what I wish to know slightly differs from the ones I already read I suppose.

I will give you an example of the problem I am facing:

Let's say a hacker has managed to infiltrate the system and is able to spoof a DNS. Now if this hacker would clone a website, let's say this website is facebook, what I have read so far he would be making a HTTP website, because HTTPS would show up as faulty.

Now what I'm wondering is that with modern SSL it would seem like everyone is able to get his own certificate for his website. So if someone would connect to that website it would say the connection is trusted because it's SSL with a legit connection.

So what if this hacker would add a certificate to his cloned/spoofed phishing website? Wouldn't this mean that me as a user would go to his facebook page, and in the search bar it would say the connection is legitimate ( Because he added a certificate ) ? Because if that would be the point it would be necessary to check the certificate of every website I open at all times to see if it's actually the certificate that belongs to facebook (For example.)

Please let me know if anyone has any knowledge about this I am very curious to see how this works!

Comment: You can not just go and create certificates for arbitrary domains you do not own. The hacker would need the certificate Facebook uses.

Comment: @CBroe: well, if the DNS is compromised and I therefore own facebook.com (to take OP's example), I can request a TLS certificate - the evidence that I own the domain will be provided via a page in the root server, an entry in the DNS or something similar. So yes - a basic certificate could be generated for that hacked domain (and then false page).

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit for the question

Comment: @WoJ well yeah, in case the hacker can take control of the DNS “globally.” But from the question it rather sounded like the hacker just got access at some local network level, and was able to fake the DNS response there. (Which DNSSEC should help prevent.)

Comment: @CBroe: I mean "Let's say a hacker has managed to infiltrate the system and is able to spoof a DNS". I read it as "the hacker own the DNS entries for facebook". It is true however that it can mean anything (what is "the system", what does "spoof a DNS" mean?)

Comment: Well if we assume the hacker is able to fully control DNS, they could get a certificate with domain validation. Getting one that also includes organization verification would still be much, much harder. But since our example site Facebook here does seem to use a certificate with domain validation only, the user would not even be able to check that the certificate “belongs to Facebook”, as OP put it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Provided that**

> Let's say a hacker has managed to infiltrate the system and is able to
>   spoof a DNS.

means that the attacker has **control over the records** for the name `facebook.com` (in orther words, he can point `www.facebook.com` to an IP of his choice) then **yes, your scenario is correct**.

He would

1. redirect `www.facebook.com` to site of his
2. buy a certificate for `www.facebook.com`

Someone going to that site would then see (`www.facebook.com` would be the domain)

[image]

This means that the traffic to access to this site is correctly secured between the browser and that site, **and nothing else**. Specifically, this does not tell if the site actually belongs to Facebook.

There are some sites which go one step further, with [Extended Validation Certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate), where the issuer does some checks to "ensure" that the certificate is delivered to the actual owner of the service. You the see something like

[image]

As you can see, the owner of the site is visible right on the toolbar. Other browsers usually use a bright green toolbar to signal such sites.

Comment: I don't believe it's trivial easy (anymore) to buy a cert for domain you don't own. This subject was raised like 8 years ago - it was very easy back then (compare here: https://www.sslshopper.com/article-is-it-trivially-easy-to-get-a-cert-for-a-domain-you-dont-own.html).

Comment: @Luke: "own" for normal certificates is defined as "put a file in the root directory of the web site" or "put a record in DNS for the domain". This is how Let's Encrypt will check your "ownership" for instance. EVCs (which I mentioned) are supposed to carry more "ownership weight" - in the sense that the issuer has checkd that you "legally" own the site (how they check depends on the CA but they will usually require some paperwork)

Comment: Correct. Still the CA should not be vunerable for DNS spoofing (try many sources). In this case 'put a record in DNS for the domain' is not obvious to achieve...

Comment: This is not the CA which is spoofed - this is the DNS record of the hacked site (please see the first sentence of my answer - there may be other interpretations of the OP question, per the first comments below the question)

Comment: That is not what I mean :-) 
You said: "own" for normal certificates is defined as "put a file in the root directory of the web site" or "put a record in DNS for the domain"

To pass the test - put' the file' test / 'add a record' test you need to modify DNS... so CA would need to be vunerable for spoofing as well.

Comment: No, the CA does not play any role here. You own the DNS entries for facebook (on the DNS server which hosts them) and then you can pretend to be facebook to, for instance, Let's Encrypt (who will ask you for the file on teh server or a record on the DNS you just pwned)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136561/discussion-between-luke-and-woj).

Comment: To summarize - as long as we're talking about that kind of DNS spoofing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_spoofing CA plays essential role. 
If someone hacked your DNS/Domain account you're not safe...

Comment: This is exactly the answer that I was looking to find, thank you very much for clearing that up.

Like you said the essence of the question was basically "Can hackers give a phishing website a certificate to make it look legit to end-users"

My apologies if my question was a bit vague, I'm an intern here for a security company and they've been asking me to check their network for any security risks as a project.

You've all been very helpful though! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Schmickle: Thanks. If you have all the information please mark the question as "answered" by ticking the check mark at the left of an answer (below the vote buttons) - it will turn green.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you're asking, but you have trusted CAs imported to your browser (by default). 
The attacker would need to have a key signed by trusted authority for this particular domain. I do not expect that to happen.

Another option would be breaking the key - very unlikely with current technology/regular updates made by major browser providers.

Major browsers providers are deprecating vunerable alghorighms to make sure you're OK.
For instance - Recently for that reason SHA1 got depreceated.
See here for more details on SHA1:

https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/11/18/countdown-to-sha-1-deprecation/#pjXdGbOji3itBI7v.97

https://security.googleblog.com/2016/11/sha-1-certificates-in-chrome.html

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=firefox+sha1+deprecation&rlz=1C5CHFA_enAU714AU715&oq=firefox+sha1&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2293j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
)

To summarize - your browser will let you know that there is 'something wrong' with the site (warning instead of green box). 
Simply check the green box (and domain). Keep your browser updated.

Also for more information about SSL handshake see here: https://www.ssl.com/article/ssl-tls-handshake-overview/

Comment: This is not how I understand the question; OP mentions taking over the **DNS** for the attacked domain and then what I mentioned in my comment to the question could happen)